# Why I can not create a table in this way?

Tags: mysql, sql

Why I can not create a table in this way, I get an error?

```
CREATE TABLE `dynamusic_album` (
    `id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cover` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `artist` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `published` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
    `genre` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `rating` DOUBLE(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

My Error:

```
    ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)' at line 9
```

SQL version = 5.1.15

Comment: I don't see any **DEFAULT '1.0' AFTER `genre`'** lines in your `CREATE TABLE` statement

Comment: I'm not an expert of MySql but maybe you should remove the quotes around the default value of 'rating'. So `rating DOUBLE(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1.0`

Comment: @RobertKock quotes around `1.0` is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While specifying numeric datatypes, especially handling decimal point values, you need to specify two arguments. So, `DOUBLE(11)` needs to be changed.

```
CREATE TABLE `dynamusic_album` (
    `id` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cover` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `artist` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `published` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `description` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
    `genre` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
     -- assuming you need at most 2 decimal places for rating
    `rating` DOUBLE(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.0', 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Refer: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html

> MySQL permits a nonstandard syntax: FLOAT(M,D) or REAL(M,D) or DOUBLE
>   PRECISION(M,D). Here, (M,D) means than values can be stored with up to
>   M digits in total, of which D digits may be after the decimal point.
>   For example, a column defined as FLOAT(7,4) will look like -999.9999
>   when displayed. MySQL performs rounding when storing values, so if you
>   insert 999.00009 into a FLOAT(7,4) column, the approximate result is
>   999.0001.

Comment: Good explanation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `DOUBLE` instead of `DOUBLE(11)`. AFAICS, MySQL does not know a `DOUBLE(x)`, only `DOUBLE(M,D)` (see [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html))